# How to show all the toolbar buttons in Tinymce 5?

Tags: tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

I recently migrated from tinymce 4.8.1 to 5.3.1 community version. After making some changes, everything looks good except one thing, getting MORE button. It shows only one row of toolbar buttons and to see rest of the buttons I have to click on MORE(...) button. Is there any property or way to show all the buttons like we show in tinymce 4.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar_mode

You can see all toolbar buttons with changing toolbar mode.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for but couldn't find.